Filter deep nested related_set in Django
There are two models:
class Subject(Model):
    categories = ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='subjects')

class Category(Model):
    parent = ForeignKey('self', related_name='subcategories')

This supposed to be translated into the following rest output:
[
    {
        ...,
        "categories": [
            {"subcategories": [{}, {} ... {}]},
            {"subcategories": [{}, {} ... {}]}
        ],
    },
    {
        ...,
        "categories": [
            {"subcategories": [{}, {} ... {}]},
            {"subcategories": [{}, {} ... {}]}
        ],
    }
]

The problem is to have set of subcategories for each category, subcategories that are in many to many relation with ancestor subject.
So far I think that queryset should be something like:
Subject.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        lookup="categories",
        queryset=Category.objects.filter(parent__isnull=True)
        .prefetch_related(
            Prefetch(
                lookup="subcategories",
                queryset=Subquery(
                    Category.objects.filter(
                        parent__pk=OuterRef("pk"),
                        subjects__id__in=OuterRef(OuterRef("pk")),
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        .distinct(),
    ),
)

But this gives the error:
AttributeError: 'Subquery' object has no attribute '_chain'

What is wrong with the queryset. What would be the correct way of doing that?

So there are only two levels? Then wouldn't it make more sense to define a Category model and SubCategory?

@willeM_VanOnsem I actually don't think so. We chose to use a plain structure, and it plays well. Things are already agreed upon and consolidated. What was the mistake, in my opinion, to serve categories with subcategories in one endpoint. I think if there is a need for filtered nested objects, they should be separated.

@willeM_VanOnsem In that case, I have the following solution: it is possible to define categories and subcategories as SerializerMethodField and pass from SubjectSerializer down to these nested fields the 'subject_id` with the context, which can be used to filter subcategories. Of course, I'm still happy to learn how to prepare queryset for such a case.

ok, but then it is not really clear how Subject maps to categories and subcategories: it has a many-to-many realtion. But imagine you link to a subcategory without linking to its "parent" category, then the prefetching will not help.

@willeM_VanOnsem I have discussed this scenario with my team, and they assured me that all the valid subactegories are connected to the subject through Category. The current queryset will just ignore such objects. It works well at the moment.

The way you are trying to do in a single statement is neither neat nor efficient.
a better approach would be using a recursive function and then arrange the response.
you can have a look at following.
def get_sub_categories(category):
    """
    This is a function which we are using recursively to get all subcategories for a catefgory 
    """
    category_data = {'name': category.name}
    subcategories = category.subcategories.all()
    if subcategories:
       category_data['subcategories'] = [get_sub_categories(subcategory) for subcategory in subcategories]

    return category_data

using above function you can get the desired response for your given subject.
subject = Subject.objects.get(id=subject_id)
categories = subject.categories.all()
data = [get_sub_categories(category) for category in categories]

your data will look like following, further on you can make tweaks to get the required fields as per your need
[
    {
        "name": "Government Exam",
        "subcategories": [
            {
                "name": "SSC",
                "subcategories": [
                    {
                        "name": "Physical",
                        "subcategories": [
                            {
                                "name": "Body 1"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Body 2"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Written",
                        "subcategories": [
                            {
                                "name": "Socialogy"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Enviromental"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "NDA"
            }
        ]
    }
]


Thank you for your response. I didn’t put an accent that there are two levels only, not more. I thought it would be understood from json example. Thank you for your effort though. Do you think you have an idea for two levels queryset?
